Spring Security Oauth2 Token Introspection
When I'm issued a new jwt access token from the Spring security Authorization server, its always evaluated as active false by the Spring Security /oauth2/introspect endpoint, even though when decoded its active

logs:
2024-11-04T23:27:27.225+01:00 TRACE 26360 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationProvider : Retrieved authorization with token
2024-11-04T23:27:27.225+01:00 TRACE 26360 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationProvider : Did not introspect token since not active

expecting the introspection endpoint response to be active:true
Authorization server config:
private static final String[] WHITELIST_URLS = {
 "/register", "/demo", "/authInfo", "/items"
};

@Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain asSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .cors((cors) -> cors
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
      );

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .requestMatchers(WHITELIST_URLS).permitAll()
    );

    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
      .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(
      e ->
        e.authenticationEntryPoint(
          new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")
        )
    );

    http
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
      .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    http
      .logout((logout) -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler()));

    return http
      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain appSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/logout", "/register", "/resetPassword", "/savePassword", "/changePassword"));
    http
      .cors((cors) -> cors
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
      );

    http
      .httpBasic(withDefaults())
      .formLogin(withDefaults())
      .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .requestMatchers(WHITELIST_URLS).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
      );

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings () {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
  }


This does not happen in official samples, so it is likely a misconfiguration somewhere. Please provide more information. How are you obtaining the token? Please provide exact steps to reproduce.

I use the authorization code which I get from the authorization server after user login - then I POST the authorization code to "/oauth2/token" with basic auth client+secret and the code as "multipart/form-data"

Please try the same with the samples linked above. Both demo-authorizationserver and default-authorizationserver use messaging-client / secret as client credentials.
